# boto3 describe_load_balancers() shows nothing while aws-cli shows all

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

After banging my head with boto3 for a while, I decided to do a sanity check to make sure that the elb's and alb's that I see in the AWS console are actually there.

`aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers`

and

`aws elb describe-load-balancers`

both show results.

However, this code shows empty (no errors, but no results):

```
import boto3

def all_lb(lb_type,*args):
    try:
        if lb_type == 'alb':
            elb = boto3.client('elbv2')
        elif lb_type == 'elb':
            elb = boto3.client('elb')
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
        exit(1)

    elb.describe_load_balancers()

print("---- ELB's")
all_lb(lb_type='elb')

print("---- ALB's")
all_lb(lb_type='alb')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `all_lb()` method should return the list of ELBs and the caller should print that list (if desired).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is in elb.describe_load_balancers()

```
import boto3

def all_lb(lb_type,*args):
    try:
        if lb_type == 'alb':
            elb = boto3.client('elbv2')
            name = 'LoadBalancers'
        elif lb_type == 'elb':
            elb = boto3.client('elb')
            name = 'LoadBalancerDescriptions'
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
        exit(1)

    bals = elb.describe_load_balancers()

    for elb2 in bals[name]:
        print(elb2['LoadBalancerName'])

print("---- ELB's")
all_lb(lb_type='elb')

print("---- ALB's")
all_lb(lb_type='alb')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've clearly been doing too much haskell.  I forgot that python doesn't just return the last result.

Answer (score 2):

The code must be getting the wrong region where as the terminal is set to use the correct region.

```
elb = boto3.client('elbv2', region_name='us-west-2')
```

Set your correct region as the line above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is that what you were looking for